# How to insert image/area map into picture from CKEDITOR 3.0

Tags: ckeditor

how to insert an IMAGE/AREA MAP in an image of CK EDITOR such site
http://martinezdelizarrondo.com/imagemaps/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This one has been around for a long time: [Image maps plugin](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=26144)