# Get ckeditor to keep an image map in the sourcecode

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I like to add a map to an image in the ckeditor. I use version 4.2 Standard Package and I would be totally fine if i do that in the sourcecode area. The problem for me is that it removes the map code completely. Does anyone know where I can tell ckeditor to keep my tags?

I've found [How to insert image/area map into picture from CKEDITOR 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917277/how-to-insert-image-area-map-into-picture-from-ckeditor-3-0) for the older version. Maybe there exisits a plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the config parameter, if you set `allowedContent: true` then the tag filter is turned off.

Example:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'myTextarea', {
   allowedContent: true,    
});
```